# Superscripts and subscripts in strapi WYSIWYG markdown editor

Tags: markdown, strapi

I am using strapi cms to add content that will be feeded to mobile apps via api's. I have a content called articles and i am using WYSIWYG markdown editor provided by strapi. I want to add subscripts and superscripts in my content. Can anyone help please?
This is specific to the markdown editor provided by strapi.

Comment: I have tried what is mentioned the link which you shared. <sup></sup>. does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Markdown does not include any native support for subscript or superscript. As the [rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) explain:

> [Markdown's] syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. ... For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself.

Therefore, you can deliminate the text with `<sub></sub>` or `<sup></sup>` respectively.

However, for security reasons, many implementations disallow raw HTML. If you are using such a tool, then that tool does not offer support for subscript or superscript unless it added some new non-standard Markdown syntax for the feature. In the rare event that your tools does (most don't), I would suggest reviewing the documentation for that tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add HTML support to the Strapi editor.  At the moment the HTML will **not** be previewed within Strapi, but you can follow these steps to get it to render properly in your app.

Your basic steps are all related to `HTML-in-Markdown`. You will need to install this into your project.

Install React Markdown like this into your project:

`npm install --save react-markdown`

The repo and further options that you can configure are in the [official repo](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown).

1. add the `react-markdown` option that sets the `escapteHTML={false}` from `{true}`.
2. Then add your HTML.

You would add it to your components like this:

A. Import `react-markdown` into your file. `import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown"`

B. Code your component that is displaying the html like this.

An example could look like this: (The source option needs to return a string to parse).

```
<ReactMarkdown  
   source={document.node.content}
/>
```

Then use the option `escapeHtml={false}`.

```
<Reactmarkdown  
   source={document.node.content}
   escapeHtml={false}
 />
```

**Note:** You wouldn't want to escape the html for any inputs accessible from the front-end as this becomes a security risk.